# Password Generator (How to add constructor to this program)

Tags: java, password-generator

This is a password generator which I made from scratch but I want to add a constructor so I can use it for calling purpose, and also need to create another class to call it as well. If possible I would like to get some help on this program.
So my program basically explains on generating random numbers symbols, upper case, and lowercase. The first time I created a password generator code it didn't work too well because it gave me all uppercase or sometimes all lowercase or just symbols with no other variables
Then I made this code where I told the program that if this variable is not there it cannot create other variables until those variables are shown.

```
  import java.util.Scanner;
         class Passwd {
             public Passwd()
             {
                 System.out.println("Hello");
             }


            public static void main(String[] args) {
                 new Passwd();
                 Scanner in;`enter code here`
                in = new Scanner(System.in);
                int choice = 0;

                while (choice != 5) {
                    System.out.println("                Password Generation Menu                ");
                    System.out.println("********************************************************");
                    System.out.println("*  [1] Lowercase Letters                               *");
                    System.out.println("*  [2] Lowercase & Uppercase Letters                   *");
                    System.out.println("*  [3] Lowercase, Uppercase, and Numbers               *");
                    System.out.println("*  [4] Lowercase, Uppercase, Numbers, and Symbols  *");
                    System.out.println("*  [5] Quit                                            *");
                    System.out.println("********************************************************");

                    System.out.println("Enter Selection (1-5): ");
                    choice = in.nextInt();

                    if (choice < 1 || choice > 5)
                        System.out.println("Incorrect option....  ");
                    else if (choice > 0 && choice < 5) {
                        System.out.println("Password Length (1-14): ");
                        int passwordLength = in.nextInt();

                        char[] password = new char[passwordLength];
                        int randNum = 0;

                        if (choice == 1) {
                            for (int i = 0; i < passwordLength; i++) {
                                randNum = ((int) (Math.random() * 26 + 97));
                                while (randNum < 97 || randNum > 122) {
                                    randNum = ((int) (Math.random() * 26 + 97));
                                }
                                password[i] = (char) randNum;
                            }
                        }
                        if (choice == 2) {
                            randNum = ((int) (Math.random() * 26 + 97));
                            while (randNum < 97 || randNum > 122) {
                                randNum = ((int) (Math.random() * 26 + 97));
                            }
                            password[0] = (char) randNum;

                            randNum = ((int) (Math.random() * 26 + 65));
                            while (randNum < 65 || randNum > 90) {
                                randNum = ((int) (Math.random() * 26 + 65));
                            }
                            password[1] = (char) randNum;

                            for (int i = 2; i < passwordLength; i++) {
                                randNum = ((int) (Math.random() * 122 - 65 + 1)) + 65;
                                while ((randNum < 65 || randNum > 90) && (randNum < 97 || randNum > 122)) {
                                    randNum = ((int) (Math.random() * 122 - 65 + 1)) + 65;
                                }
                                password[i] = (char) randNum;
                            }

                        }
                        if (choice == 3) {
                            randNum = ((int) (Math.random() * 26 + 97));
                            while (randNum < 97 || randNum > 122) {
                                randNum = ((int) (Math.random() * 26 + 97));
                            }
                            password[0] = (char) randNum;

                            randNum = ((int) (Math.random() * 26 + 65));
                            while (randNum < 65 || randNum > 90) {
                                randNum = ((int) (Math.random() * 26 + 65));
                            }
                            password[1] = (char) randNum;

                            randNum = ((int) (Math.random() * 26 + 48));
                            while (randNum < 48 || randNum > 57) {
                                randNum = ((int) (Math.random() * 26 + 48));
                            }
                            password[2] = (char) randNum;

                            for (int i = 3; i < passwordLength; i++) {
                                randNum = ((int) (Math.random() * 122 - 48 + 1)) + 48;
                                while ((randNum < 65 || randNum > 90) && (randNum < 97 || randNum > 122) && (randNum < 48 || randNum > 57)) {
                                    randNum = ((int) (Math.random() * 122 - 48 + 1)) + 48;
                                }
                                password[i] = (char) randNum;
                            }

                        }
                        if (choice == 4) {
                            randNum = ((int) (Math.random() * 26 + 97));
                            while (randNum < 97 || randNum > 122) {
                                randNum = ((int) (Math.random() * 26 + 97));
                            }
                            password[0] = (char) randNum;

                            randNum = ((int) (Math.random() * 26 + 65));
                            while (randNum < 65 || randNum > 90) {
                                randNum = ((int) (Math.random() * 26 + 65));
                            }
                            password[1] = (char) randNum;

                            randNum = ((int) (Math.random() * 10 + 48));
                            while (randNum < 48 || randNum > 57) {
                                randNum = ((int) (Math.random() * 10 + 48));
                            }
                            password[2] = (char) randNum;

                            randNum = ((int) (Math.random() * 7 + 33));
                            while (randNum < 33 || randNum > 39) {
                                randNum = ((int) (Math.random() * 7 + 33));
                            }
                            password[3] = (char) randNum;

                            for (int i = 4; i < passwordLength; i++) {
                                randNum = ((int) (Math.random() * 122 - 33 + 1)) + 33;
                                while ((randNum < 65 || randNum > 90) && (randNum < 97 || randNum > 122) && (randNum < 48 || randNum > 57) && (randNum < 33 || randNum > 39)) {
                                    randNum = ((int) (Math.random() * 122 - 33 + 1)) + 33;
                                }
                                password[i] = (char) randNum;
                            }
                        }


                        for (int j = 0; j < passwordLength; j++)
                            System.out.print(password[j]);
                        System.out.println("\n");
                    }
                }
                System.out.println("Thank You for using World's Best Password generator \n");
            }
        }
```

Comment: it already has a constructor. what you want is to get all that code out of the main method, and build it into an OO design

Comment: Not much needs to be done other than getting rid of the I/O and printing, and making the type and size of the password into parameters (either in the constructor or a generatePassword method). Most of the processing could be  copied over into methods.

Comment: also take a look SecureRandom

Comment: You just need to move the code to a method, accept 'choice' as a parameter and get rid of the main method.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is apply OO principles and create a class that is responsible for generating the password, `PasswordGenerator` for example. It would look like:

```
public class PasswordGenerator {

  public String generatePassword(int passwordType) {
    // All your password generation logic
  }
}
```

So you can use it in another class.

```
public class PasswordThing {

  public void doSomethingWithPassword() {
    PasswordGenerator passwordGenerator = new PasswordGenerator();

    String password = password.generatePassword(1);

    // ...
  }

  // or

  public static void main(String[] args) {

      // Get user choice from command line as you did in your sample
    PasswordGenerator passwordGenerator = new PasswordGenerator();

    String password = passwordGenerator.generatePassword(userChoice);

    // ...
  }

}
```